# Binding ID in HTTP REQUEST in angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am learning a tutorial and an assignment on how to bind id's to http request. This is what i am currently  trying to do. I want to bind the id captured in my url and when i trigger the function, it submits the id captured from the url to my service. I am have been able to capture the url but the function to send the captured id to the service is where i am having the issues. The id in the function parameter is Unused.

```
//Food Component
export class FoodComponent implements OnInit {
private food_id;
constructor(private httpService: HttpService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        if (params['id']) {
            this.food_id = params['id'];
        }
    })
}
//food model
foodModel = {
    type: "",
    location: ""
};
sendFood() {
    this.httpService.send(this.food_id)
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        })
}
//service
send(food: any) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(food.value);
    const headers = new Headers();
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/luncheons/v1/location/' + food.id + '/type', body, {
            headers: headers
        })
        .map((data: Response) => data.json());
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show where the `sendFood()` method is called. It should be right after you retrieve the food_id from the URL. Also, why do you pass a `food_id` param to `sendFood()` and you never use it inside the method? (you use `this.foodModel` instead)

Comment: @AngularFrance i call that function when i submit my form using (ngSubmit)="sendFood(food)" #food="ngForm"

Comment: @AngularFrance, if i pass the food_id like     this.httpService.send(this.food_id), the form will be submitted empty

Comment: I see. Something's not right. On the template site, you're passing the entire form to your method (`food` represents the **entire form**, if anything it should be `food.value` to only pass the form values). On the class side, you're expecting a `food_id` param. You need to make sure you're passing the same type of data that your method expects.

Comment: @AngularFrance, could you please be more helpful ?

Comment: Looks like you're tackling too many difficult tasks at once given your current level. My understanding is that you have a form, a URL param, and an HTTP request and I'm not even sure which of the three poses a problem... Where exactly are you stuck? What is the interaction between the URL, the form and the HTTP request? You should really try to break down your goal in smaller tasks, tackle ONE task, and when it's done move on to the next.

Comment: @AngularFrance, my problem now is now to bind the id to the url in my service. i am able to submit the form values alright but the only error coming is http://localhost:8000/api/luncheons/v1/location/undefined/type', meaning the url doesn't get any id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136667/discussion-between-angularfrance-and-liska-liskor).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import { foodModel } from './foodModel';

export class FoodComponent implements OnInit {
  private model: foodModel; /// Make a new variable of foodModel.

  ngOnInit() {
    this.model = new foodModel(); // Initialize the Model

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      if (params['id']) {
        this.model.id = params['id']; ///set the parameter id to model.id
      }
    })
  }

  /// Removed the parameter food_id
  sendFood() {
    this.httpService.send(this.foodModel)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      })
  }

  //service
  send(food: any) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(food);
    const headers = new Headers();
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/luncheons/v1/location/' + food.id + '/type', body, {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((data: Response) => data.json());
  }
}

// Make a class file foodModel.ts and import foodModel in your component.
export class foodModel {
    type: any;
    location: any;
    id: number = 0; /// new variable added
};
```

Comment: cannot find name  foodModel   **this.model =  new foodModel()**  and cannot find name **    id:int = 0; /// new variable added**

Comment: Make a class file foodModel.ts and import foodModel in your component.